# Bypassing Captcha using python

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, captcha

Can we resolve the captchas using any python packages ? I had tried **pytesseract**. It solves only basic captchas. *Is there any alternative way to bypass the captchas in the link provided below ?*

**Link : https://app5.lasd.org/iic/iverifysearch.cfm**

Thank in advance

Comment: There is a bunch of posts about this here in stack, but the only one thats worked to me, was this [Tutorial](https://www.scrapehero.com/how-to-solve-simple-captchas-using-python-tesseract/). Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot achieve good captcha guess rate by using any local package or anything.

To really deal with captchas you need to use services like "Anticaptcha" and similar, google it. They provide API, you send an image to it and periodically poll for the answer (typically comes in 10-15 secs). People over there sit and solve your captchas for a small salary, so the solving rate is close to 100%.

Comment: I know paid APIs are there but i need some sort of python packages or free apis. :/ Thank you for your contribution